# SpringMVC, MessageListener and Injection

Tags: spring, redis, code-injection

Is there anyway to inject services in MessageListener?

```
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myServices")

  MyServices myServices;

  @Override
  public void onMessage(final Message message, final byte[] pattern) {
    myServices.call(); 
}
```

This way not inject service. That's because in @Configuration we do

```
    @Bean
MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter( new RedisMessageListener() );
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Just make it a bean.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: (no need for a MessageListenerAdapter if the delegate is already a MessageListener):

```
@Component
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myServices")
  MyServices myServices;

  @Override
  public void onMessage(final Message message, final byte[] pattern) {
    myServices.call(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create standalone class, you can also do this:

```
@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter messageListener(@Qualifier("myServices") MyServices myServices) {
    //use myServices instance somehow
    return new MessageListenerAdapter( new RedisMessageListener() );
}
```